# How to use JWebSocket in OSGI (apache felix)?

Tags: websocket, osgi, osgi-bundle

I want to use JWebSocket in OSGi. I think I have to package my project which is coded in JWebSocket into bundles. And then I put them in OSGi environment. But now I do not know to do it.
Could you please help me ? Please give me some ideas and some detail steps to do it.
Thank you a lot.

I list all things I did to export my plugIn to use it with a stand alone jWebsocketServer
( following this turtorial http://www.lauridmeyer.com/2012/05/developing-jwebsocket-plugins-with-eclipse-part-2/).

- I create a flugin with name myPlugin.jar
- I open the jWebsocket standard configuration file jWebSocket-1.0 → conf → jWebSocket.xml and  add your Plugin to the Plugins section
- I type this command line to start server:

  java -jar libs\jWebSocketServer-1.0.jar -home C:\Users\Laurid\Downloads\jWebSocketServer-1.0-nb20507\jWebSocket-1.0 -config C:\Users\Laurid\Downloads\jWebSocketServer-1.0-nb20507\jWebSocket-1.0\conf\jWebSocket.xml

Answer (score 1):

Probably the first step is to take JWebSocket and your project and make one large bundle out of it. This is probably not what you want to end up with, but it is a relatively easy step. You need to figure out how to start and stop JWebSocket as your bundle now has a BundleActivator with a start and stop method replacing the main method that was previously your entry point.

The next step is to start "cutting up" this big bundle into smaller ones. In that step you need to start thinking about a proper API between JWebSocket and your project. Also, you might want to look into OSGi services and see if you can leverage those. A "normal" servlet container often uses the Whiteboard Pattern to publish its endpoints. Google for that, look at the Felix HTTP documentation, and you'll get some ideas about that.

The final step then is to modularize your project itself. Again, think about APIs between the modules and the life cycle of the individual components and what your project will need to do if some modules go missing.

Hope that helps to get you started. Be more specific in your questions and I'm sure the OSGi experts can offer more advice.

Comment: I am a beginner of jwebsocket and osgi. Can you give me some turtorial.I assume that I have the plugin of this turtorial http://www.lauridmeyer.com/2012/04/developing-jwebsocket-plugins-with-eclipse/. What are next steps I have to do.

Comment: That tutorial pretty much already explains all the steps to run jwebsocket in an OSGi environment. It contains an example, you should be able to just "drop in" your application instead. Again, be more specific with follow up questions if you want good answers here.

Comment: Please for me a tutorial to do it. I have just add some specific things in my question.

Comment: Please tell me more detail @Marcel Offermans. Thank you very much